# how to use datatable add row new object to string("C2") to report in VB.NET

Tags: datatable, report

my goal is to format the currency column "MONTHLYSALARY" in the datatable to the output report. Only I still wonder how to add row new object like the code below

```
'sample code
                dt.Rows.Add(New Object() { "<b>GROSS PAY</b>", payslip.Gross.ToString("C2") })
                dt.Rows.Add(New Object() { "<b>TOTAL DEDUCTIONS</b>", payslip.Deductions.ToString("C2") })
```

```
'the code I'm using
Private Sub Generate()
        report.Clear()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Clear()
        dt.Columns.Add("ID")
        dt.Columns.Add("EMPID")
        dt.Columns.Add("NAME")
        dt.Columns.Add("MONTHLYSALARY")
        Dim query = "Select ID,EMPID,[NAME],MONTHLYSALARY From tblemployee"
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, Con)
            adapter.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        report.AddDataTable(dt)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Generate()
        report.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
    End Sub
```